# add multi records into database in the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add multi data in the database table by clicking on one button, how can I do that?

```
<?php

 if( isset($_POST['add']) ){

        $ins = "INSERT INTO informations(`cate_id` ,`location_id` , `name` ,`specialization` , `address` , `telephone` , `time`) VALUES(
    '".$_POST['category']."', 
        '".$_POST['location']."', 
    '".$_POST['name']."', 
    '".$_POST['specialization']."',
    '".$_POST['address']."', 
    '".$_POST['telephone']."', 
    '".$_POST['time']."')";
    $do_ins = mysql_query($ins); 

    echo 'Insert done';

     }

    ?>
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - he means inserting for example two row with one query

Comment: Have you tried to search this site, before asking this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic version of the mysql multi-row insert syntax:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (field1, field2, field3)
VALUES 
(value1, value2, value3),
(value4, value5, value6)
```

With the above query, 2 rows are inserted:
`(value1, value2, value3)` and `(value4, value5, value6)`

-- EDIT --

For your form, you can use array-like syntax in your form input names to pass the variables along to PHP in an array.  If you're using locations, you can do something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="locations[0][name]" />
<input type="text" name="locations[0][address]" />

<input type="text" name="locations[1][name]" />
<input type="text" name="locations[1][address]" />
```

The above inputs will fill out the following `$_POST` or `$_GET` entries:

```
$_POST['locations'][0]['name']
$_POST['locations'][0]['address']

$_POST['locations'][1]['name']
$_POST['locations'][1]['address']
```

As you can see, this allows you to use a loop to go through each location.

```
$locations = array();
foreach($_POST['locations'] as $location) {
    $fields = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $location);

    $locations[] = "(\"{$fields['name']}\", \"{$fields['address']}\")"; 
}

$insert = "INSERT INTO locations (name, address) VALUES " . implode(',', $locations);
mysql_query($insert);
```

You'll most likely want to add some validation code to make sure they're actually filling in all the fields as well.

Comment: But how can i insert many by ++ and by many inbut fields  ?

Comment: THANK YOU IT'S VERY GOOD CODE .

Comment: BUT I AM SO SORRY I WANT ASKED ANOTHER QUESTION ... HOW CAN I ADD UNLIMITED INPUT FIELDS BY DYNAMIC WAY WHEN CLICKED ON ADD NEW BUTTON ?